# Change the number of products per row, depend on screen size Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the number of products per row (category page), depend on screen size.

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
   var width = jQuery(window).width();

   if(width >= 1000 && width <= 1200){
     jQuery('.sentry-product').removeClass('columns-4').addClass('columns-3');
     }
   else{
     jQuery('.sentry-product').removeClass('columns-3').addClass('columns-4');
     }
})
.resize();
```

I'm using this jQuery to change the number of possible columns,
I need to change the number of product as well,

Now I'm hardcoding the number of products

```
        function storefront_product_columns_wrapper() {
        $columns = storefront_loop_columns();
        echo '<div class="sentry-product columns-' . intval( $columns ) . '">';
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_loop_columns' ) ) {
    /**
     * Default loop columns on product archives
     *
     * @return integer products per row
     * @since  1.0.0
     */
    function storefront_loop_columns() {
        return apply_filters( 'storefront_loop_columns', 4 ); // 4 products per row
    }
}
```

I have another idea,
If I can pass the number of product as a parameter from the class name it will fix the issue - return apply_filters( 'storefront_loop_columns', X );

I don't understand if I can do it, Some ideas?

Comment: Use media queries instead if you can and hide the extra products you don't want to see.

Comment: I have no problem whit the CSS, I want to change the PHP...

Comment: If you want to change the number of product when the user resize the screen, you will need ajax to get the number of products that you want and put it in the page.

Comment: Don't try to solve display issues serverside. Pass all the products (for one page) to the user, and let CSS handle the correct width based on the device widths. I suggest you look into flexbox and/or media queries. Fact that php decides the columns is probably cause of the CRM having options for people that cannot write code

Comment: My problem is that I can't prevent the default behavior of the Woocommerce page, Is it possible to "solve display issues serverside", I cant control the number of product in a row in CSS...

Comment: To clarify, it's woocommerce that's outputting a fixed number of items per row so changing the CSS is ineffective; for instance changing product width from 30.75% to 45% (3 columns to 2) results in a single product on line 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do it with three columns, reducing to two on a viewport of 600px or less;

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.woocommerce.columns-3 ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page.columns-3 ul.products li.product {
   width: 45%; /* was 30.75% */
}

.woocommerce ul.products.columns-3 li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products.columns-3 li.product {
  width: 45%; /* for category pages */
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.first, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.first {
  clear: none; /* was both */
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.last, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.last {
  margin-right:3.8%; /* was 0 */
}
```

Obviously you'll have to adjust for a different number of columns or breakpoint. And I'm about to write another set for 480px so I can have one product per row on phones. This CSS comes after woo commerce's CSS (or use `!important`)

Comment: Personally, in this day and age I think using .last and .first (or pseudo equivalents) is a bit of a kludge.

Comment: And just to say, you don't need any Javascript for this. It all works with woo commerce's default output.